# Cannot find a way to execute a ruby script from within swift

Tags: ruby, swift

I have searched the web and the Swift documentation,
but so far have not found a way to execute a ruby script.
Is there a way to do this?  I am assuming the script
exists as a file on the system.

Comment: If you want to run ruby within "swift", you should probably use rubymotion (??)

Answer (score 1):

Using `system` worked for me. The following calculates 5 factorial in Ruby under Swift:

```
import Cocoa

let value = 5
system("ruby -e \"p (1..\(value)).inject{|a,b| a*b}\"")
```

Comment: I know this is like two years late, but would it be possible to _get_ the value _from_ a ruby expression in Swift?

Comment: @AntonBelousov Correction: "'system' is *now* unavailable...".  The answer was correct when given in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

This use to be possible in Objective-C through MacRuby, but It didn't offer much benefit over the other options unless you need to interact very heavily between the two environments. MacRuby is more for interacting with the Objective-C world from Ruby than vice-versa, but it does allow you to freely mix the two languages in your project.

Sadly, MacRuby has effectively been dead in the water for a couple of years now. It had a lot of promise, but it didn't have the necessary internal support at Apple for it to succeed.